# Azure Blob Storage - High Server Latency (3sec where SLA says ms)

Tags: performance, azure-blob-storage, low-latency

I'm trying the performance of a mobile app storing images in `Azure Blob Storage`.
When profiling my app I noticed a storage query with a near 3s Time to First Byte. I downloaded the related Azure Storage log file and noticed that both the End to End latency as well as the Server Latency where near 3s. The SLA says latency should be in range of ms.
Note that I am the only user of my app as I'm stil developing it.

Some infos:

- this is a general purpose storage account located in West Europe, North Europe
- I'm based in France
- I use [MS Storage SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net) to query the storage account
- It uses Shared Access Signature (SAS)
- An example of query:
   https://{myaccoount}.blob.core.windows.net/{Container}/{filename.jpg}?sv=2015-04-05&sr=c&sig=wEtcqKsJRl5ouxUceTTXgzVLk7bDoMvLJITlPTLEFRo%3D&se=2016-09-17T16%3A15%3A16Z&sp=r&api-version=2015-07-08&randomguid=3dde0ba3a14047eaba0d186902fee650
- Metrics are automatically written in Tables and logs in Blobs.
- It's not a network issue as ServerLatency is high (see [doc](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-monitoring-diagnosing-troubleshooting/#metrics-show-low-AverageE2ELatency-and-low-AverageServerLatency))

Any suggestions on how to improve latency and why it's not in ms?

Comment: It should be okay. Is it a network issue?

Comment: It would be a network issue if the metric was AverageE2ELatency but it is AverageServerLatency (see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-monitoring-diagnosing-troubleshooting/#metrics-show-low-AverageE2ELatency-and-low-AverageServerLatency)

Comment: Are you using standard or premium storage account? you may try premium if not using currently.